# Running sync code asynchronously in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, concurrency

I need to fetch some data using multiple calls. My code is **synchronous**, and I can call a synchronous `getData` method (which makes a network request) multiple times to get everything. To improve performance, I want to execute all these calls concurrently using coroutines, but I don't know if this code is really doing what I want it to.

My relevant Kotlin code looks roughly like:

```
fun getAllData(): List<Data> {

  val coros = listof(1, 2, 3, 4).map {
    num -> GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { getData(num) }
  }

  return runBlocking { coros.awaitAll() }
}
```

I can edit this code, but I cannot edit the `getData` method.

Is this code running the `getData` calls concurrently? I'm suspicious that wrapping this in an async block doesn't solve the issue as presumably somewhere inside `getData` I need to await/return control back to the async block to continue to the next call, which I am not doing since `getData` is synchronous.

If this isn't running concurrently, is there any way I can make the calls behave asynchronously? Would the overhead of threads typically be worth the time saved in making multiple concurrent network requests?

Comment: Is using coroutines a requirement? If not, and you're using Kotlin/JVM, then one option would be to use the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework. You could create an `ExecutorService` with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, `submit()` your calls to it, and then `get()` the results from the returned `Future`s  as needed.